# Only enable visual styles for specific controls

Tags: c#, winforms

In Windows Forms visual styles can be enabled for all controls by calling `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`, but is it possible to only enable visual styles only for specific controls?

I want to disable visual styles for `MonthCalendar` in order to control the look accross operating systems, but want e.g. `Button` to have the look of the theme in the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ctzxs7w.aspx), you might have to actually disable visual styles for all controls to achieve this, especially for MonthCalendar control (check the Note section).

Hope this helps!